# Ubuntu touch terminal

Tags: command-line, ubuntu-touch, unity8

From googling around I have noticed that Ubuntu touch does have a terminal program.

I have the amd64 image of Ubuntu desktop next(15.04) installed in a multiboot environment.However I just can't find the terminal inside of it?Where is that thing?

Answer (score 0):

There is no *amd64* emulator for the phone images yet. As such, I am not entirely sure if it is supported as an architecture by the framework and store. Also, it is still somewhat difficult to create click packages which support all architectures. As a result of that, it will take time for apps to become packaged for multiple architectures.

Comment: So basically there is none yet for amd64?

Comment: If it does not appear in the store scope, it is not packaged for the architecture or frameworks you have, yes.

Comment: too bad...I wanted to test apt-get...